# Redirect Home page to external url

Tags: magento-enterprise, url-rewrite

is there any way for redirecting magento home page on a external link using magento admin url rewrite functionality. What I tried so far you can see in picture.

[image]

Update:- My question was never related to what are the other option to do this. My question was related to Magento url rewrite like home page redirection to external website is possible or not.

Comment: Good question. Have you tried if empty request path is possible? Normally the request path entry in Magento redirects should not end with a slash. And I see another problem, it's Target ***Path*** that means, you can only place a path component in tthere (not fully true, it can be path, query, fragment but only by error), you can not place an absolute URI in there. so no start with `https?://` or `://`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use htaccess Redirect instead.

1.open notepad

2.place this code

Redirect 301 /old-url    http://www.newurl.com

### 3.save as .htaccess and place it on the root where your index page is.

How to redirect webpages code generator can be found here:
http://www.htaccessredirect.net

Comment: i want to do from admin, not from server side. I know about server redirection.

Comment: @Saurabh: What is wrong with configuring this on the level of the webserver? I think Vvvaida raises a good point in her answer.

Comment: @hakre: I already know about server configuration but I am curious about magento if is this possible from admin?

Comment: @Saurabh: The only way I'm aware of in the admin for that is by setting the base-URL to the URL you want to redirect to. But then the redirect is of code 302 and not 301. An not only from the homepage (but only to the homepage/base-URL).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do a `redirect from your site to external url using Url Rewrite`.

**Url rewrite only do redirection into you instance.**

**You configure will do like redirection:**

YourSite/ -> YourSiteUrl/http://redesign.goori.com

Better `way do htaccess redirection.`

In this case,you can use `event&Observer` by

controller_action_postdispatch_cms_index_index

because  this event call whenever call home and

**Use for redirection to  3rd party site**

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

- See more at: https://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-url-redirect-from-controller/#sthash.ONtDDuXh.dpuf

Comment: it is possible from admin panel, it is working for category page, there is just problem with home page.

Even if I access home page with myurl/home then Magento url rewrite work.

for that case :- request path :- home and Target Path :- external url

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera,
I used observer for url rewrite, the issue I'm facing here s,
 - when i enter the existing url(www.example.com/faq) in the request path and route's the same in browser it's reaching the correct external target url(www.google.com). (Working)
 - when I enter the new url(www.example.com/test) in the request path and route's the same in browser it's not reaching the correct external target url rather gives the 404 page. (not working)

I'm using the grid and saving the dates in db.

Can you suggest me the solution!!!